# Add-AzureADAdministrativeUnitMember throws error insufficient privileges

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to create a runbook to add users an administrative unit in Azure AD.
Anyone able to add members to an administrative unit using a service prinicpal, or know if it's even possible at this point? The module containing the commands is in preview.. Any clues would be appreciated.

It works fine when running it with my regular admin account, but not with the AzureRunAsAccount..
These are the API permissions added to the automation service principal

[image: API permissions]

I've even tried to grant the principal global admin rights in the tenant.

Here is the script I'm running:

```
Import-Module -Name AzureADPreview

$Conn = Get-AutomationConnection -Name AzureRunAsConnection
Connect-AzureAD -Tenant $Conn.TenantID `
-ApplicationId $Conn.ApplicationID -CertificateThumbprint $Conn.CertificateThumbprint

$XXAU = Get-AzureADAdministrativeUnit -ObjectId "REMOVED"
$XXAUMembers = Get-AzureADAdministrativeUnitMember -ObjectId "REMOVED" | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID
$XXUsers = Get-AzureADGroup -SearchString "REMOVED" | Get-AzureADGroupMember | Select -ExpandProperty ObjectID


Foreach ($XXuser in $XXUsers){
    if($XXAUMembers -notcontains $XXuser){
        Add-AzureADAdministrativeUnitMember -ObjectId $XXAU.ObjectId -RefObjectId $XXuser
    }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
Add-AzureADAdministrativeUnitMember : Error occurred while executing 
AddAdministrativeUnitMember 
Code: Authorization_RequestDenied
Message: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
RequestId: 
DateTimeStamp: Fri, 19 Jul 2019 20:14:39 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

Comment: Have you looked at this, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/manage-runas-account ?

Comment: Yes, nothing useful there as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you sure the `Global admin` not work? There may be some delay, could you try again?

Comment: Any update this issue?

Comment: I ended up using an admin user with stored credentials in the automation account, with the Privileged Role Administrator role. I might go back and try to troubleshoot the service principal at a later point, just needed it to work.